# How to capture the error message in private function

Tags: java, assert, assertion

I have a function compare which called private function compareRuleRanks, and println the error or correct message when condition met, how can I capture the message when I do unit test? I try to use AssertionError but  didn't work, how can I do that?

```
AssertionError(dataCompare.compare("Rule1", "Rule2"));
```

```
public void compare(){
       compareRuleRanks(rule1, rule2);
}

private void compareRuleRanks(rule1, rule2) {
   if(rule1.rank != rule2.rank) {
     println("The ranks are not in order");
   }
   println("rules are same");
}
```

Comment: Neither of your functions returns anything.  Why not have `compareRuleRanks` return `true/false` as well as printing its result, and have `compare()` return that value as well.  Then in your test, you can test the return value of `compare()`.

Answer (score 0):

When unit-testing `compareRulesRanks`, you can definitely call the function but you would have to measure whether the intended reaction was triggered.

That means you would have to check whether `println()` got called as expected.
If you cannot do that you probably have to improve your code for testability.